# reactjs setState in IE11 takes forever/blocks the UI

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, internet-explorer-11

I have this logic that I have to support in IE11 (rip) and I fetch a ton of HTML from the server

Using React 16.5

All is good and dandy until I parse this into a list, then set the parsed list as an array in state

I pass `items`down as a prop to a List.jsx component

The issue here is I `.map` Through this list during `render` and when I profile it after calling `setState` it takes the GUI foreverrrr to render and it freezes up the UI

So I decided that react doesn’t yield occasionally to prevent UI blocking I guess?

So in that component I have the thought to `return false` within `shouldComponentUpdate` and just manipulate the DOM like we use to with jquery and append explicitly the parsed items from the server so that I can yield within my looping logic.

What would you do if you know how to use React for a solution to IE11 freezing up because I cannot use a virtual list; all items must be in the DOM or would of used a virtual list. (Other than refactoring the entire page logic I cannot use a virtual list)

Should I call `setState` a multiple of times each time appending more to the list array in the state at top level until all items are appended so it can process smaller items each render caused by the `setState` within my List.jsx component or, or, or...

ill try to shell out some code example

```
function getItems() {
   return [{item: '<tr><td>one</td></tr>', attributes: {}}, {item: '<tr><td>two</td></tr>', attributes: {}}]
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
    state = {
      items: [],
    }
    componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({
        items: getItems()
      })
    }

    render() {
       return (
           <List
             items={this.state.items}
           
           />

       )

    }
}

class List extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
          this.props.items.map((item, i) =>
              <tr
                  key={i}
              >
                  {i}
              </tr>
          )
        )

    }



}
```

Any advice is great,
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet?

Comment: Can you test with a newer React version?

Comment: A CodeSandbox would be great if you can.

Comment: I cannot provide full fledged code, sorry. The concept is conveyed I hope, i added small edit as well and will try to update React but will need to check for breaking changes first

Comment: I didn't reprduce the issue with the code you providing in IE 11. The result is [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpWyD.png). My test code sample is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ufjvgx?file=index.html). I use react 16.12.0. You could provide [a minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can reproduce the issue and see how to help. We don't want all the source code, you could hide the private information and unrelated part in your code.